# Problem with blinking cursor (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, games

I was just playing game that I downloaded from steam and after I just restarted PC I get black screen with blinking cursor and Idk what to do, please someone help.

Comment: Does there is any message displayed ? Any character ?  A `#` ?  Your username ? Can you type on the black screen ?